# how to find child elements or tags within a tag in beautiful soup?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hi so i have been web scraping a lot of different sites, but am stuck here . can any one please help.

This is how the html is structured with Huge spaces in the class name

I am using beautiful soup

```
<div class="nw-priceblock-container">

   <del class="

          nw-priceblock-amt

          nw-priceblock-mrp

          is-having-discount

          ">Rs. 699 </del>

   <span class="

          nw-priceblock-amt

          nw-priceblock-sellingprice

          is-having-discount

          ">Rs. 489 </span>

   <span class="nw-priceblock-discount is-having-discount"> (30% Off)</span>

</div>
```

i want to get the Rs.489 text/value

Comment: Show your current code. Also don't break original HTML indentation - it's OK to leave as it is

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html ="""<div class="nw-priceblock-container">

   <del class="

          nw-priceblock-amt

          nw-priceblock-mrp

          is-having-discount

          ">Rs. 699 </del>

   <span class="

          nw-priceblock-amt

          nw-priceblock-sellingprice

          is-having-discount

          ">Rs. 489 </span>

   <span class="nw-priceblock-discount is-having-discount"> (30% Off)</span>

</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

# find parent class
# print(soup.find('div', {'class': 'nw-priceblock-container'}))
parent_clsss = soup.find('div', {'class': 'nw-priceblock-container'})

# print(parent_clsss.find('span', {'class':'nw-priceblock-discount is-having-discount'}).text)
print(parent_clsss.find('span', {'class':'nw-priceblock-discount is-having-discount'}).find_previous('span').text)
```

Answer (score 0):

so i solved it by defining a function and doing the try and except block

```
def Price(p):
   try:
    return p.find("span", class_='nw-priceblock-sellingprice').text.replace("Rs.","").replace(",","")
   except:
    return 0
```